# Compiling with clang-cl works, but linking fails to find basic libc symbols

Tags: clang, msvc12

For my language ([Runa](https://github.com/djc/runa)), which compiles to LLVM IR, I'm trying to enable compilation to Windows. I would like to enable linking with MSVC-compiled stuff, so I want to use an MSVC target triple. I installed MSVC Community 2013 and have a `cmd.exe` window where I've run the accompanying `vcvars32.bat` script, so that a bunch of MSVC things have been added to `PATH`. However, when trying to compile, I get the following linker errors:

```
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol malloc referenced in function runa.malloc
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol free referenced in function runa.free
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memcpy referenced in function runa.memcpy
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol write referenced in function runa.unhandled
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol exit referenced in function runa.clean
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Unwind_RaiseException referenced in function runa.raise
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol snprintf referenced in function float.__str__
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strlen referenced in function uint.__str__
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __chkstk referenced in function str.__eq__
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strncmp referenced in function str.__eq__
hello-163edf.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
```

I understand the one about `_Unwind_RaiseException`, that probably doesn't fit in with this target, but it's not clear to me why basic libc stuff like `malloc()` cannot be find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these were solved by adding `/link msvcrt.lib` to the end of my compiler invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your build process and version of visual studio, you may need msvcrt, vcruntime and ucrt. See this post for a more in-depth explanation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/